# Falha ao executar App no android studio

Tags: android

Boa tarde Pessoal,
eu estou precisando de uma ajuda por favor,
eu estou executando o meu App no meu celular e também no meu emulador mas em ambos os casos o meu app fica desse jeito como mostrado na figura em anexo, dai queria uma ajudinha sua por favor.

Jailson[image: Design do meu app[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLmn9.png)

Aqui está o script de activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App"
        android:textColor="#00aacc"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="170dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNome"
        android:layout_width="290sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nome"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editApelido"
        android:layout_width="290sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Apelido"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="158dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhone"
        android:layout_width="290sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="222dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="290sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="287dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLimapr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="365dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSalvar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="365dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Qual Layout está usando? Relative? Constraint?

Comment: Qual é a falha?

Comment: Vinicius Lino estou usando o blanch layout

Comment: O problema é no layout que você escolheu. Passe o código XML pra gente dar uma olhada.

Comment: Jota você pode postar o código do Layout aqui, por favor?

Comment: a falha é que a app não mostra o design correctamente porque deveria preencher a tela

Comment: posso enviar o file txt porque não consigo colocar o código todo

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta e coloca o código do XML lá...